# Coudn't save Many-to-many code first Db

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using code first and fluent api this is my models

```
public Admin()
        {
            this.course = new HashSet<Courses>();
        }
   [Key]
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string LoginName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Courses> course { get; set; }
}

 public Courses()
            {
                this.admin = new HashSet<Admin>();
            }
      [Key]
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public virtual ICollection<Admin> admin { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Admin>()
                .HasMany(e => e.course)
                .WithMany(e => e.admin);
```

and this is my controller which I'm getting the courseid from cshml

```
  public ActionResult Admins( Admin rec, IList<int> CourseId)
  {

      foreach (var item in CourseId)
        {
            var cr = new Courses();
            cr.ID = item;
            rec.course.Add(cr);
 }
  db.Admins.Add(rec);
  db.SaveChanges();
```

it gives me error when I'm trying to save db.SaveChanges()

could any one tell me what's the wrong here ?

Error Message

> Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that EF assumes the `Courses` instances that you add to the `Admin.course` are new. You need to let EF treat them as existing by either using `DbSet<T>.Attach` method or `DbEntityEntry.State` property:

```
foreach (var item in CourseId)
{
    var cr = new Courses();
    cr.ID = item;

    // Here:
    db.Entry(cr).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    // or alternatively:
    // db.Courses.Attach(cr);

    rec.course.Add(cr);
}
db.Admins.Add(rec);
db.SaveChanges();
```